# How to update a web component's shadow DOM when its size changes?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am developing a web component that renders some graphics on a `<canvas>`, that appended to the component's `shadowRoot`

I would like to re-size and re-render the canvas when the size of the element changes (e.g. its CSS `width` property is updated).

How to do so? Should I be using a `ResizeObserver`?

Comment: "*What is the best way to do so?*" This core of your question highly opinion-based without putting concrete, measurable metrics into what you *yourself*, in *your* specific situation, consider when making such a determination as to what is "*best*". Please edit your question to include which metrics you are evaluating in making such a decision.

Comment: Changed to "How to"

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a `ResizeObserver` in the constructor of my custom element:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
    // re-render my canvas
  });
  resizeObserver.observe(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer @Steren provided, but will add one more detail which might help others like me.

The component might default to a style `display: inline` and cause the `resizeObserver` not to work. So by setting it to `dispaly: block` the observer will be fired when the component resizes.

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
    // re-render my canvas
  });
  resizeObserver.observe(this);
  this.style.display = "block"
}
```